# "Cannot use a method returning play.libs.F.Promise[play.mvc.Result] as an Handler " in Play 2.1.2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using Play framework 2.1.2, I have a handlere method that returns a Promise as documented in Play's 2.1.2 [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/JavaAsync)

but Play throws Compilation error saying:

> Cannot use a method returning play.libs.F.Promise[play.mvc.Result] as an Handler

Am I missing something to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give your promise to the `async()` method to do that.

```
Promise<Result> futureResult = ...
return async(futureResult);
```

This method returns an `AsyncResult` – when Play is given an AsyncResult, it waits (non-blocking) for the result to be computed, then sends it.

Read [JavaAsync](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/JavaAsync) for more details (especially the `AsyncResult` part.)

Comment: Thanks Stephane, thats what I am currently doing. But this is causing an action's clean up code to run before the request is completed. Please see this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055690/in-play-framework-how-to-run-some-clean-up-code-in-a-play-action-only-after-an